# Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to import a json file to firestotre using javascript but I am getting this error when I do `node import.js`, :[image]

Here is my import.js file:

```
// Imports
const firestoreService = require('firestore-export-import');
const firebaseConfig = require('./config.js');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');

// JSON To Firestore
const jsonToFirestore = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Initialzing Firebase');
    await firestoreService.initializeApp(serviceAccount, firebaseConfig.databaseURL);
    console.log('Firebase Initialized');

    await firestoreService.restore('./carapp-96076-default-rtdb-export.json');
    console.log('Upload Success');
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

jsonToFirestore();
```

These are all the files I have in my git repository.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please Help!

My Json file looks like this:
[image]

Comment: There's some examples of the expected JSON in [the documentation](https://github.com/dalenguyen/firestore-backup-restore#for-http-request). What do yours look like?

Comment: Code goes in your question. Please [edit] it

Comment: You cannot restore an array. It should be an object with the properties being the collection names

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). What line is throwing that error?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `json` structure is not in the required format as shown in the [link](https://github.com/dalenguyen/firestore-backup-restore#for-local-json) of `firestore-export-import`

Here I have recreated the setup but with my custom json file:

```
const { initializeFirebaseApp, restore } = require('firestore-export-import')
const firebaseConfig = require('./config.js');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

console.log('Initializing Firebase');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL
});
console.log('Firebase Initialized');
// JSON To Firestore
const jsonToFirestore = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('Upload Started');
      await restore('./data.json');
      console.log('Upload Success');
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  jsonToFirestore();
```

Where my `data.json` is structured as follows:

```
{
  "test": {
    "Hobart": { "id": 1, "first_name": "Hobart" },
    "Mitzi": { "id": 2, "first_name": "Mitzi" }, //… like documents 
  }
}
```

This has successfully restored the json file into firestore collection of `test` having Hobart , Mitzi , etc as document ids and if you want to generate auto-incremented ids then you can just replace outside curly brackets to boxy brackets as shown in this [link](https://github.com/dalenguyen/firestore-backup-restore#import-data-to-firestore-auto-generate-document-id).

Then json structure for storing documents as auto-generated ids will be as follows:

```
{
  "test": [
    { "id": 1, "first_name": "Hobart" },
    { "id": 2, "first_name": "Mitzi" }, //… like documents 
  ]
}
```